# Running magento2 commands in Windows XAMPP

Tags: magento2

I am using XAMP for magento2. I am not able to run commands and getting error:

> php is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file

I try these commands: `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2>php bin/magento indexer:reindex`, `php\bin\magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Check my response.

Comment: You can directly run php commands from shell provided with xampp.You will have to navigate to magento root to run magento commands though.

Answer (score 3):

You can run php pages using php.exe create some php file with php code and in the cmd write:

```
[PATH to php.ext]\php.exe [path_to_file]\file.php
```

Example Case for you:

```
1. My XAMPP is installed on D:\php\ and php.exe resides in D:\php\php and Magento folder is here D:\php\htdocs\MG\m212 ( http://localhost/MG/m212/)
2. Re-indexing:   
    i. Go on to D:
    ii. D:\php\php>php D:\php\htdocs\MG\m212\bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

On XAMPP

```
 Installed Xampp_root/php>php   'Path_to_project'
```

It will work for you.

***EDIT:***

1. Go to php installation: `cd c:\xampp\php\`
2. After that run: php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento indexer:reindex

Comment: i didn't get u jai

Comment: Check update answer and try @pawan's respone too.

Comment: ,so each time i run those type of codes i have to add "php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\" ad prefix isn't it

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. Good luck

Comment: if you want to use it in this way use this ./../../php/php.exe bin/magento. But this also not help to reduce time for executing command

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your PHP path is added to your windows system's environment variable. After that you may able to run commands successfully.

Here is tutorial [Add PHP to Your Windows Path Variable](https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/) will help you

Or you can try below command

C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Command**

> D:\xampp7.2\php\php.exe D:\xampp7.2\htdocs\m232\bin\magento indexer:reindex

---

`Use In Batch File`