# How to deploy Static Content in Windows 7 for Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2

How can we deploy static content in Magento 2.1.6 in windows by command line.

Comment: you are using xampp? mention clear in question please.

Comment: Yes,  i am using xampp.

Comment: Try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186169/running-magento2-commands-in-windows-xampp/186178#186178

Answer (score 0):

1) got to installed xampp directory

2) example c:\xampp\htdocs\magento2(your magento folder)>

3) run the below command 
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your local magento installed directory. Probably, C:\xampp\htdocs\yourMagentoRootPath
2. `D:/xampp/php/php -dmemory_limit=2G  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`,

Here: `D:/xampp/php/php` is Your php installed directory, `-dmemory_limit` is used to set memory limit(It is optional), `bin/magento` - you can find the bin directory in magento root installation(id not exists it will not works), `setup:static-content:deploy` - It is the command.