# How to use Magento 2 Basic Command in Windows CMD?

Tags: magento2.3

I'm new in Magento 2
I'm using XAMPP, Windows 10 and use CMD for Run Magento2 basic Commands,
but I don' know how to use that in CMD,
BCS when I have run this command

```
php magento indexer:reindex
```

give me an error like this: **'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**
operable program or batch file

My Magento 2 Path is : **C:\xampp\htdocs\m231>**

also, 
I have setup PHP as an environment variable.

**Path = ;C:\xampp\php;**

**My Testing Commands:**

**C:\xampp\htdocs\m231>** **php magento setup:upgrade**

'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

**C:\xampp\htdocs\m231\bin>** **php magento setup:upgrade**

'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

**C:\xampp\htdocs\m231>** **magento indexer:reindex**

'Magento' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

**C:\xampp\htdocs\m231\bin>** **magento indexer:reindex**

'Magento' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

but not working.

Please give me some solution.

Thanks.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186169/running-magento2-commands-in-windows-xampp

Comment: Can you please try to use php bin/magento command once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `C:\xampp\php` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Then close your command prompt and restart again.

***Note:***
Please close your command prompt and restart again otherwise changes will not be reflected.

*If you like the answer please give thumbs up. :)*

Comment: Yes Its Working Now. Thanks

Comment: How to run chmod permission commands on windows cmd? @Yo Yo Roshan

Comment: @zus Refer this -> https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-chmod-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

you can download cmder for better use of commands.